# How to get charts data on click of respective column in SAP UI5

Tags: sapui5

I have column chart currently being displayed using SAP UI5

How can I get X axis and column value on which the user clicked

Comment: which column chart (makit or viz chart??) what have you tried so far?? Have you looked into `selectData` event for the chart? you will get the parameter. Put it in console.log and have a look at the properties

Comment: I am using Viz chart. Yes i have used select data event but not able to find out the details about the measure and dimension of the column i click